# MVC 3 JSON Model binding not creating object

Tags: json, asp.net-mvc-3

This was my first attempt at JSON MVC model binding and things aren't going according to plan.... massive sigh! In every attempt when I break in the controller action the strongly typed model/class is either empty or null.

What I do:

Client side I'm generating an array to store payments

```
var PAYMENTS = new Array();
```

Payment values are entered by a user and added into the payments array. Some of the fields will only be populated server side once data is posted, so I assign temp values.(reference, userID)

```
PAYMENTS.push({ reference: "0",
            paymentDate: date,
            paymentMethodID: paymentMethod,
            paymentAmount: amount,
            bankNameID: bankID,
            bankBranchCode: branch,
            drawerName: drawer,
            chequeNo: chequeNo,
            userID: "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000",
            statementNo: statementNo,
            additionalReference: additionalRef
        });
```

After adding 2 payments, this is the firebug result for PAYMENTS

```
0 Object { reference="0", paymentDate="31-01-2012", paymentMethodID="7", more...}
1 Object { reference="0", paymentDate="31-01-2012", paymentMethodID="0", more...}
```

User selects to process the payments which calls processPayment()

Practices are a 2nd parameter that should be passed, but just trying to get payments working first.

```
function processPayment() {

    var paymentsJSON = $.toJSON(PAYMENTS);
//  var practicesJSON = $.toJSON(selectedPractices);

    $.ajax({
        url: BASE_APP_URL + "Payment/processPayment",
        type: 'POST',
        data: "{ param : '" + paymentsJSON + "'}" ,
        contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function (data) {
            alert(data);
        }
    });
}
```

viewModel Class. I've simplefied the viewModel types in an attempt to get something into the controller.

```
public class paymentsViewModelJSONPayment
{
    public string referece { get; set; }
    public string paymentDate { get; set; }
    public string paymentMethodID { get; set; }
    public decimal paymentAmount { get; set; }
    public string bankNameID { get; set; }
    public string bankBranchCode { get; set; }
    public string drawerName { get; set; }
    public string chequeNo { get; set; }
    public string userID { get; set; }
    public string statementNo { get; set; }
    public string additionalReference { get; set; }
}
```

finally controller action

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult processPayment(List<paymentsViewModelJSONPayment> param)
{
    return Json(param);
```

When debugging:

Post values from Firebug:

```
JSON


param   "[{"reference":"0","paymentDate":"31-01-2012","paymentMethodID":"7","paymentAmount":500,"bankNameID":"8","bankBranchCode":"","drawerName":"","chequeNo":"","userID":"00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000","statementNo":"","additionalReference":""},{"reference":"0","paymentDate":"31-01-2012","paymentMethodID":"0","paymentAmount":500,"bankNameID":"10","bankBranchCode":"0026","drawerName":"drawer","chequeNo":"00231021","userID":"00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000","statementNo":"","additionalReference":""}]"
```

Breakpoint in controller. The action gets called but no binding.

Not allowed to post images yet, but when breaking controller List is empty.

From watchlist:

> - param   Count = 0   System.Collections.Generic.List
> - Raw View                Capacity    0   int         Count   0   int
> - Static members
> - Non-Public members

I'm pretty much out of ideas, tried various configurations and kinda lost count of everything I've tried.

Will greatly appreciate any help.

Thanks a stack.

Answer (score 3):

Try specifying `500.0` for the `paymentAmount`. I like to use Fiddler2 to test out things like this: http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/.

This link sheds some light on binding decimal values: http://digitalbush.com/2011/04/24/asp-net-mvc3-json-decimal-binding-woes/

**EDIT**: I set up a test project using your classes and was able to POST your JSON (but tweaking the `paymentAmount`) using Fiddler to the controller without any problems.

The request is shown in the top pane, the response (formatted as JSON by Fiddler) in the bottom.

The `referece` property in your class is misspelt, so that comes back as `null`.

[image: Fiddler Screen Grab]

Comment: I just removed my answer as I just seen MVC3 is now perfectly able to bind JSON back to an object if it is the only parameter in the post action. If you need different bindings to occure for each parameter in your post action than a custom JSON binder would fit but I think it is overkill for this question and it propably is as simple as the `500.0` :).

Comment: I tried changing the model by making amount type 'string' and posting it as a string without success. Found a solution just now, will post answer.

Answer (score -1):

The only way I could get a value bound to 'param' was by defining it as string. I then used the JavascriptSerializer to deserialize it into my desired object.

```
[HttpPost]
public JsonResult processPayment(string param)
{
    JavaScriptSerializer serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
    try
    {
        List<paymentsViewModelJSONPayment> payments = serializer.Deserialize<List<paymentsViewModelJSONPayment>>(param);
```

param value at breakpoint

```
"[{\"reference\":\"0\",\"paymentDate\":\"01-02-2012\",\"paymentMethodID\":\"7\",\"paymentAmount\":500,\"bankNameID\":\"8\",\"bankBranchCode\":\"\",\"drawerName\":\"\",\"chequeNo\":\"\",\"userID\":\"00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000\",\"statementNo\":\"\",\"additionalReference\":\"\"}]"
```

payments value in VS watchlsit

```
    payments    Count = 1
System.Collections.Generic.List<PCNS.viewModels.paymentsViewModelJSONPayment>
    [0] {PCNS.viewModels.paymentsViewModelJSONPayment}  PCNS.viewModels.paymentsViewModelJSONPayment
    additionalReference ""  string
    bankBranchCode  ""  string
    bankNameID  "8" string
    chequeNo    ""  string
    drawerName  ""  string
    paymentAmount   500 decimal
    paymentDate "01-02-2012"    string
    paymentMethodID "7" string
    referece    null    string
    statementNo ""  string
    userID  "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000"  string
```

Seems like a bit of a hack, but it's working.

Comment: Did you try posting to your controller using something like Fiddler changing the JSON to use `paymentAmount: 500.0`. Note that I'm not suggesting you POST `paymentAmount` as a `string`.

If you use Fiddler you'll need to set the `Content-Type` in the headers.

Comment: Apologies Dave, didn't intend for my posting paymentAmount as string to come across as your suggestion, I did this before reading you reply. Posting a actual decimal value also failed (500.0, 500.05), I'm obviously missing something. For time being I'm sticking to my current solution and will revisit once I have a bit more time.

Comment: No problem, I just wanted to make sure my suggestion was clear. The class, JSON and controller snippet you supplied all worked fine for me. I would recommend trying with Fiddler to eliminate any issues with the client-side code.