# MVC nullable + localization fail

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc-4

In my country (Croatia), currency values are formatted like this:

> 123.456.789,00 kn

I have MVC application that requires the user to enter a price of something. My model represents that field with `decimal?` variable. When user enters this number:

> 5.678,22

MVC returns this error message:

> The value xxx is not valid for the field.

although that number is correctly formatted. After I've changed my variable data type from `decimal?` to just `decimal`, everything works (user can enter number 5.678,22 and MVC doesn't return an error).

So my question is: what's going on? Is it possible that this is some kind of a bug in .NET framework? I'm using .NET framework 4.5.

Answer (score 0):

[This Stack Overflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9082119/mvc-3-json-model-binding-not-creating-object) may be able to assist you, or you can just more directly check this [Blog by Phil Haack](http://haacked.com/archive/2011/03/19/fixing-binding-to-decimals.aspx), he uses a customized model binder that detects your Culture Info when binding decimals.